# Output to HTML issue

Tags: powershell

Hello newish to PS and i am having an issue getting the Output data to output.

The HTM file is created but no data, what am I missing here, again im newish!

This is to check TSM backup report and to start service if down.

Here is the script

```
$serverlist  = gc servers.txt
$SvcName = '*tsm*scheduler*'
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\"
$date = "{0:yyy_MM_dd-HH_mm}" -f (get-date)
$file = $filepath + "Results_" + $date + ".htm"
New-Item $filepath -type directory -force -Verbose 

 $Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
<title>
 TSM Report
</title>
"@

ForEach ($server in $serverlist)
{

$Tsm = Get-Service -ComputerName $server| Where {$_.name -Like $SvcName}     


If ($Tsm.StartType -ne 'Automatic')
{

    Set-Service -InputObject $Tsm -StartupType Automatic
}
If ($Tsm.Status -ne 'Running')
{
    $output = "Starting the service."
    Start-Service -InputObject $Tsm
}

$Tsm2 = Get-Service -ComputerName $SysName | Where {$_.name -Like $SvcName}


} 
 $pre= "Here are the results for $date"

 $Tsm2 | Select-Object DisplayName, Status, StartupType | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $pre | Out-File $file

Invoke-Item $file
```

Comment: what does `$output | Select-Object DisplayName, Status, StartupType` return? is it returning properly?

Comment: no data is displayed in the htm file looks like this with no data- Here are the results for 2017_07_14-11_07 DisplayName Status StartupType

Comment: Remove all the lines with `$output =` and then just use `$Tsm2 | Select-Object DisplayName, Status, StartupType | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $pre | Out-File $file`

Comment: Thank you, kind of working now but im missing Server name being output to the file I tried like $server | Out-File $file - I updated the post with how the script is now

Comment: Then add `MachineName` to the `Select-Object`. Also use `@Username` to tag a person in your post, so they are notified of a reply.